# Can you run a sliding window analysis on a raster in R and specify window size that is not a multiple of the cell size?

Tags: terra, sliding-window

I have several covariate layers that vary in resolution I would like to run sliding window analyses on all of these layers with a window size of 800m. This window size is important to maintain exactly as it is ecologically relevant, but not all layers have cell sizes that are divisors of 800, meaning I don't believe I can use terra's focal() function which requires window size to be specified by number of cells.

I have included an example image that helps illustrate what I am hoping to accomplish.

[Moving window in purple, summarizing 800m window around cell in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lg70.png)

Are there any packages that allow you to use a non-cell size related moving window and weight the pixels by area that are only partially included in the window?

Comment: Please edit your question and include a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*.

Comment: What about `terra::zonal()` function with `z` as 800m `SpatVector` and `weights` set to `TRUE`?